# Docker CLI failing to compose with "Additional property postgres is not allowed"

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-cli

My docker-compose.yml looks like this

```
postgres:
    container_name: postgres-container-1
    image: postgres:latest
    ports:
        - "15432:5432"
```

When I try to run

```
docker compose up -d
```

I get following error

```
(root) Additional property postgres is not allowed
```

However when I run

```
 docker-compose up -d
```

everything runs as intended, but I get info message that

```
Docker Compose is now in the Docker CLI, try `docker compose up`
```

So I assume that docker-compose will soon be obsolete... What did I do wrong?

Comment: can you please paste the entire compose file ?

Comment: In particular, do you have top-level `version:` and `services:` keys?

Comment: This is the entirety of docker-compose.yml file. Nothing more nothing less

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I had this issue as well. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38717025/docker-compose-file-is-invalid-additional-properties-not-allowed) other StackOverflow post fixed it for me.

I needed the `services:` key at the top, with `postgres:` nested under it.

My docker-compose.yml

```yaml
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password1
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: some-db
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    volumes:
      - ./sql/setup.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue and Here is how i was able to solve it.

```
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:15-alpine
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment: 
      POSTGRES_DB: webapp_dev
      POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: trust
```